# How to set priority in CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE config?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, celerybeat

In my Django app, I am trying to set the priority value to 6 for a Celery beat task, but the below doesn't work. What's the right way to set this value? I have other tasks in this config and want to set different priority values.

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
  'some_task_name': {
    'task': 'app_name.tasks.some_task_name',
    'schedule': crontab(hour=18, minute=30),
    'options': {'priority': 6}
  }
}
```

Comment: Which transport protocol are you using?  I think currently only RabbitMQ and Redis has support and it sounds like you have to set it up to tell it to schedule based on priority:  https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/routing.html#special-routing-options

Comment: I have Redis, and priorities are 0..9. How do I set which task is which priority in the config?

Comment: The link I provided says you have to set the `queue_order_strategy` to `priority`.  Have you done the things outlined under "Redis" on that page?  I'm not familiar with setting "options" in the SCHEDULE so I have no idea if that's right or not...

Answer (score 0):

Your beat schedule config looks right, you do need to make sure you set `queue_order_strategy` in the app config as well.

```
app = Celery(
    'tasks',
    broker=f'redis://...',
)

app.conf.broker_transport_options = {'queue_order_strategy': 'priority'}
app.conf.task_default_priority = 1

app.conf.beat_schedule = CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE
```